# how to save data from dynamic textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

this code creates a textbox dynamically based on the total number of items in a listview. my problem is how can i access these textboxes so i can save the contents of the textbox to my database?

```
int f = 24;
int j = 25;
for (int gg = 0; gg < listView1.Items.Count;gg++ )
{
 j = f + j;
 TextBox txtb = new TextBox();
 txtb.Name = "tboxl1"+gg;
 txtb.Location = new Point(330,j);
 txtb.Visible = true;
 txtb.Enabled = true;
 txtb.Font = new Font(txtb.Font.FontFamily,12);
 groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtb);
 }
```

Comment: I don't known what conventions you are following but it's better in the for loop to name you variable like i, k, j,.. or x, y, z,.. it is not a must, but it is more readable and faster to grasp the meaning because most of the people used to use i, k,j and immediately will recognize that it is a loop variable (most of the time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be more inclined to write you code like this:

```
var f = 24;
var j = 25;

var textBoxes =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, listView1.Items.Count)
        .Select(gg =>
        {
            j = f + j;
            var txtb = new TextBox();
            txtb.Name = String.Format("tboxl1{0}", gg);
            txtb.Location = new Point(330, j);
            txtb.Visible = true;
            txtb.Enabled = true;
            txtb.Font = new Font(txtb.Font.FontFamily, 12);
            return txtb;
        })
        .ToList();

textBoxes.ForEach(txtb => groupBox2.Controls.Add(txtb));
```

Now you have a variable `textBoxes` that saves references to the new text boxes. You can use that to get the values from the text boxes to save them to your database.

Comment: im basically new to c# and i'm still not so familiar with this.

Comment: one more thing. i cant access var textBoxes on a different method. i have a save button in which i want to access the textboxes. i forgot to mention the dynamic textboxes is generated in formload

Comment: @DeviruchiDDevourer - You can declare the `textBoxes` list to be a form-level variable then you can access it from any method. Do it like `private List<TextBox> textBoxes;`. Then remove the `var` from the code in my answer.

Comment: i know this is a lot of spoon feeding but can you please include how can i access each textbox on the list?

Comment: got it working now. thank you so much for your help. i use this to extract the texts from every textbox inside the list.
 foreach(TextBox txtb in lsttb)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(""+txtb.Text,""); 
            }

Answer (score 1):

If you want all `TextBox` controls then:

```
        foreach (Control control in groupBox2.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                string value = (control as TextBox).Text;
                // Save your value here...
            }
        }
```

But if you want a specific `TextBox`, you can get it by its name like this:

```
Control control =  groupBox1.Controls.Find("textBox1", false).FirstOrDefault(); // returns null if no control with this name exists
TextBox textBoxControl = control as TextBox; // if you want TextBox control
string value = control.Text;
// Now you can save your value anywhere
```

Comment: iv'e tried to create a method that would loop out the items and display them but i get an error

Comment: private void check_score()
    {
     for (int fr = 1; fr <= listView2.Items.Count;fr++ )
     {
     Control ctrl = groupBox1.Controls.Find("tboxl2" + fr, false).FirstOrDefault();
     TextBox tbctrl = ctrl as TextBox;
     string value = ctrl.Text;
     int af = Convert.ToInt32(value);
     MessageBox.Show("asd: "+af,"");
            }
        }

Comment: What's your error?! Did you check for null value in case of wrong TextBox name?

Comment: i used the method of @Enigmativity and seem to got it working thank you for the replies

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reference to  text box as follows,

```
Control GetControlByName(string Name)
{
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
       if(c.Name == Name)
          return c;

    return null;
}
```